# How to know whether Mac has SSD or HDD installed

Tags: mac, macos, disk-utility, ssd, hdd

How do I know whether my Mac has a SSD or HDD installed without having to literally open my Mac?

PS. Is there anyway to know it from Disk Utility?

Comment: Hold it up to your ear haha

Comment: Does it start in a second?

Comment: Yeah it starts in 8 seconds.

Comment: @DanBeaulieu It seems there is no other way now. You ignited me.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

- Apple Menu -> About This Mac -> System Report
- Select Storage in the Hardware section
- Select "Macintosh HD" on top

[image]

Alternatively you can run `system_profiler SPSerialATADataType` or `system_profiler SPStorageDataType` in Terminal which more or less gives you the same information

Comment: Only the terminal command lines worked for me.I have a SSD installed in my Mac.

Comment: Disk Utility and then Info tells you as well, as does "about this mac", and the storage tab there. Tells the bus type too (SATA/PCI/USB)

Comment: For macOS Big Sur(11.6.4), none of methods you provided tells HDD now. It's strange.

Answer (score 2):

Apple Menu -> About This Mac -> System Report -> Hardware -> SATA/SATA Express

For my MacBook Pro (Early 2015) this showed the Serial-ATA Device Tree, from which I was able to get the model number for my SSD. This related question, [How to get serial number from Mac hard disks?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2019244/6417219) might help if you think you have an HDD.

Comment: Does NOT work for macOS Big Sur(11.6.4) now.

Comment: @DawnSong Works just fine on macOS Big Sur (11.6.5). The path is Apple Menu > About this Mac > System Report > Hardware > Storage > Physical Drive.

Answer (score 1):

1. Click the Apple logo in the top left corner of the desktop.
2. Click About This Mac.
3. Click Storage.
4. Under the hard drive icon will be a description of the hard drive type such as Flash Storage which means it has an SSD installed.